# how to use combine date part in search statement of sql server?

Tags: sql-server

```
select * 
from employee
where DATEPART(MM ,empDOJ) + DATEPART(yy,empDOJ) < 2013 + 5
```

I want employee detail from table "employee" where date of join of employee is less than may 2013 but above query is not working properly and "empdoj" is date in sql

Answer (score 1):

correct way of doing this would be

```
select *
from employee
where empDOJ < convert(date, '20130501', 112)
```

But you can use string '20130501' or '2013-05-01' because when you compare it to date column, SQL Server will convert data types according to [data type priorities](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).  Since `date` type is higher priority than `varchar` type, SQL will convert `varchar` to `date` implicitly:

```
select *
from employee
where empDOJ < '20130501'
```

Note that using functions on your column prevent from using indexes on this column, so when you're writing where `datepart(MM ,empDOJ) = 5` index (if you have index on `empDOJ` column) will not be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPDOJ < '2013-05-01'
```